# How to do partial text matching in Excel?

Tags: excel, text, vlookup, matching, partial

I have a list of job positions (no definite number of records) that I would like to classify under some job scopes (252 records) in Excel.

[Job positions/Job Scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht2D0.png)

I want to do partial text matching so that Excel would match each job under "Job Position" to a category under "Job Scope" accurately. However, my data for job position varies for each row, so i can not match position and scope word for word.
For now I have used Vlookup in Excel. However the results I got were irrelevant and does not make sense.

[Vlookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQCGG.png)

My formula in Excel is "**=VLOOKUP($A$2:$A$341,Classes,1,TRUE)**"
Classes is the name I used for Job Scopes

How can Developer be classified under Dentist??

I have thought of using IF statement in Excel, however I have a lot of job positions to consider and have many more positions that have yet to be included in the list. Hence, using the IF statement would be very time-consuming.
Is there a way VLookup can be smarter? Or an alternative way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

The first variable in vlookup should not be an array it should be a single value.

The second is that vlookup doesn't do partial matches.  You have vlookup set as true at the end so it assumes your lookup array is in alphabetical order and it returns the the cell that would come before your searched for value by spelling.

I don't really understand your data to provide a proper solution but that's why vlookup is doing what it is.

Comment: The first value might be an array. Just use array formula in such a case. Also don't use vlookup, go for index+match.

Comment: That is true but in the way he used it I don't think he was looking for an array formula and I don't think it would return anything meaningful.

Comment: @gtwebb
Ohh i understand. If I send you a copy of my data is it possible to help me find a solution? I'm pretty new at excel and I don't know what to search to help myself either.